# Generating set of points satisfying constraints (logic conditions)

Tags: python, constraints, sampling, mixed-integer-programming, polyhedra

Suppose that we have the following formulation for a mixed-integer linear programming without considering its objective function. i.e. A set

$$X = {(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{Z}^m \; | \; Ax +Bz <= d}$$

(I don't know how to put latex code here...)

Also suppose that constraints Ax + Bz <= d can be written also in form of logic function (i.e. a function which returns true when it satisfies the given condition).

Now, I'd like to sample a set of points in the set X, only by giving specifying dimensional constants m and n.

One way that I though was using monte-carlo type algorithm, but since it seems like a brute force and it may take so many time for complex constraints, I decided to not use them.

Would there exist any better solution to the problem USING PYTHON ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is this your homework? >:(

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: I just wanted to check performance of an optimization model using bigger data.